# Using output of CELL as input of FIND

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wanted to look for a character in excel file location so that they can be sorted out. The formula which I used gives #Value error.

```
=FIND(CELL("filename"),"]")
```

It seems like FIND is not able to take output of CELL as a string.
How do I make outer formula to use output of the inner formula as input in such nested formulas.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the parameters of the FIND the wrong way around... It should be:

```
=FIND("]",CELL("filename"))
```

Then it should work the way you wanted it.